# How to use the white blank in filename in scp command

Tags: bash

I have downloaded a video in my vps,download it into local pc.

```
mv  "Protests continue in Portland, Oregon _ LIVE-daAaLP8m6WU.mp4"  portland.mp4
scp root@$ip:/tmp/portland.mp4  /tmp
```

I got it in my local directory `/tmp/portland.mp4`,how to make the following command execute?

```
scp  root@$ip:/tmp/"Protests continue in Portland, Oregon _ LIVE-daAaLP8m6WU.mp4"   /tmp
scp: /tmp/Protests: No such file or directory
scp: continue: No such file or directory
scp: in: No such file or directory
scp: Portland,: No such file or directory
scp: Oregon: No such file or directory
scp: _: No such file or directory
scp: LIVE-daAaLP8m6WU.mp4: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the spaces.

```
scp 'user@host:/tmp/Protests\ continue\ in\ Portland\,\ Oregon\ _\ LIVE-daAaLP8m6WU.mp4' portland.mp4
```